# Lasso + Correlation to rank features and assumption check

Tags: correlation, lasso

I am considering using Lasso regression in combination with variable's correlation to target variable to rank features. Initially, I rank the important variables using Lasso regression. Subsequently, I use correlation as a secondary criterion to rank these variables. I'm uncertain whether it's necessary to verify Lasso assumptions in my case. Does checking the assumptions still matter in my approach?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What LASSO assumptions do you want to check? Depending on what you want to do, I don't necessarly see any assumptions being made by LASSO estimation.

Comment: I only want to rank important variables. Next, I will use an optimization algorithm to select the top % variables. I don't see the need to check assumption, but I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.